# Rownumber() function of RDLC report isn't correct

Tags: .net, report, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, rdl

Below figure is my report. 
This tablix has 10 row from dataset.

It's grouped by TOOL_CODE and TYPE for get count.
At "Count" Column is use this expression ..

```
   = Count("Detials")
```

"Detials"  is a name of group(by TOOL and TYPE)

And No.Column I use expression by Rownumber() function like these

```
   = Rownumber(Nothing)
```

It's wrong because Rownumber() refer to items in dataset. 
It's not count from row which is display.

[image]

Comment: interesting! I guess you could add custom function to increment for each actual report row.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem.

At "No." Column use this expression

```
  =RunningValue(CountDistinct("TableName"),Count,"TableName")
```

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
=RowNumber(Nothing)
```

I like it also for the fact that it will number grouped sets of data independently, so you know the total in each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an expression at the detail level of `=RowNumber("[tablename]")`